# Get authorization code off azure using selenium chrome webdriver in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-graph-api, authorization

My goal is to write a script which would let a user login to Microsoft Azure by opening a chrome browser window. And once the user has been successfully logged in, I want to capture the authorization code from the redirected uri.

So far, I am able to open the window, user logs in and the authorization code is generated. However, I am struggling to get the authorization code back in my script. I need the code to be able to gain AAD access token. In a bigger picture, I am trying to list the users details of my tenant in my Azure subscription (but this part comes later).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import requests
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service


def launchBrowser():

    url= 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={clientid}&response_type=code&redirect_uri=myAppredirectUri}&response_mode=query&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default&state=12345'

    driver.get(url)
    # need code to get the authorization code here. current_url is returning the URL back and not the url once user has successfully loggedin. 

service_obj = Service(pathtochromeexe)
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver=webdriver.Chrome(service=service_obj, options=options)



launchBrowser()
```

Comment: Don't do this with Selenium. Implement AAD login in your application, declare your scopes, and let users choose whether to accept them.